# How does GB18030 differ from Unicode?

Tags: unicode

How does the Chinese GB18030 code set differ from Unicode?

What special techniques are required for handling GB18030?

Are there any (open source) libraries for handling GB18030?

Comment: you confuse character sets (like Unicode) with character encoding schemes (like GB18030, ISO Latin-1..15, UTF-[7,8,16,32]).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [Wikipedia article on GB18030](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030), "GB18030 can be be considered a Unicode Transformation Format (i.e. an encoding of all Unicode code points) that maintains compatibility with a legacy character set." That is, all Unicode characters can be encoded in GB18030, but they will be encoded with different byte sequences than would be generated with UTF-8 or UTF-16. Handling the GB18030 encoding doesn't require any more special techniques than are required for any other non-Unicode encoding.

The [ICU project](http://www.icu-project.org/) is an open source library (for C or Java) that has full support for many different encodings, including GB18030. Information on converting between different encodings with ICU can be found [here](http://icu-project.org/userguide/conversion.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm moderately aware of ICU; I wasn't aware that it handled GB18030 too, though.

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong in saying that "GB18030 can be be considered a Unicode Transformation Format". Whoever wrote that does not understand the meaning or "Transformation Format". One might consider that valid if there would be an algorithmic way to map between GB18030 and Unicode, without mapping table. If mapping tables are involved, then the two are just two independent encodings that can cover the same character set. Same as KOI8-R is not a "Transformation Format" of iso-8859-5, and Shift-JIS is not a "Transformation Format" of EUC-JP

Comment: @MihaiNita: According to the Unicode glossary, a [transformation format](http://unicode.org/glossary/#transformation_format) is a "mapping from a coded character sequence to a unique sequence of code units (typically bytes)", and a [coded character sequence](http://unicode.org/glossary/#coded_character_sequence) is an "ordered sequence of one or more code points". As long as there is a mapping of each Unicode code point to a series of bytes, it seems that it can be considered a "Unicode transformation format".

Comment: Unicode is an open standard, meaning the characters in it increase (or get modified) over time. So I believe at a certain point of time Unicode and GB18030's snapshots share the same set of characters. But in the long term, the two might diverge.

Comment: @KunWu: Unicode 2.0 and later define a maximum of 1,112,064 code points. GB 18030 defines how to map between every one of them. If Unicode were to ever to beyond this, UTF-16 would inherently be broken as well.

Answer (score 15):

> What special techniques are required for handling GB18030?

The biggest thing to be aware of is that, unlike UTF-8, GB18030 allows ASCII bytes to occur within the encoding of a multi-byte character.  (For example, 'ß' is encoded as the bytes 81 **30** 89 **38**, which contains the ASCII encoding of '0' and '8'.)  This means that you can't use a simple byte-oriented `find`/`index` function.